# shinyapps.io cannot save data to Dropbox: Disconnected from server once upload a file

Tags: shiny

I build a small app to test if I can upload a file in the app and save the uploaded file into Dropbox. It works well in my local Rstudio, but when I deploy it to shinyapps.io, I got the "disconnected from the server" as soon as I upload my file. I am in a Mac OX environment and following are my codes:

```
ui.R:
library(shiny)
library(rdrop2)

ui=shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    fileInput("upload", "Upload", multiple = FALSE)
))


server.R: 

library(shiny)
library(rdrop2)
outputDir <- "test"

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 

  token <- readRDS("droptoken.rds")
  drop_acc(dtoken = token)

  dataInput <- reactive({

    file1 <- input$upload
    clientData <- read.csv(file1$datapath, header=TRUE)
    clientData
  })

  GetUserName <- function() {

    x <- Sys.info()[["user"]]
    if (is.null(x) | x == "") {
      Sys.getenv("USERNAME")  
    } else {
      Sys.getenv("LOGNAME")  
    }

    if (identical(x, "unknown")) {
      warning("unknown returned")
    }

    return(x)
  }

  observeEvent(input$upload, {

    saveData(dataInput())
  })

  saveData <- function(data) {

    fileName <- sprintf("%s_%s_%s.csv", GetUserName(), as.integer(Sys.time()), digest::digest(data))
    filePath <- file.path(tempdir(), fileName)
    write.csv(data, filePath, row.names = TRUE, quote = TRUE)
    drop_upload(filePath, dest = outputDir)
  }

})
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:-

```
fileName <- sprintf("%s_%s_%s.csv", GetUserName(), as.integer(Sys.time()), digest::digest(data))
filePath <- file.path(tempdir(), fileName)
write.csv(data, filePath, row.names = TRUE, quote = TRUE)
drop_upload(filePath, dest = outputDir)
```

Try this:-

```
fileName <- sprintf("%s_%s_%s.csv", GetUserName(), as.integer(Sys.time()),
write.csv(data, fileName, row.names = TRUE, quote = TRUE)
token <- readRDS("droptoken.rds")
    drop_acc(dtoken = token)    
drop_upload(fileName, dest = outputDir,dtoken=token)
```

It worked for me.
Note: save your token in .rds file and do it once on your local machine. Don't include below code in your code when publishing to shiny server.

```
    #token<-drop_auth()
    #saveRDS(token, "droptoken.rds")
```